# Interpretation of this Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Why is it necessary to write $F(x)$ instead of just $F$?

Usually I only see $\int_0^xf(t) dt$ where $0≤x≤1$ so why does $F$ need to be a function of $x$?

Can I interpret the mapping $L$ as $L(f)=\int_0^xf(t) dt$ where $0≤x≤1$?

Comment: $L(f)$ is a function, so you have to define what $L(f)(x)$ is for each $x$. This is precisely what the image depicts, where $L(f) = F$.

Comment: @GuidoA.  So the $x$ in $F(x)$ is unrelated to the upper bound of the integration nor the bounds from 0 to 1?

Comment: I thought that $L(f)$ is a function where $f$ is the input?

Comment: $L$ is a function that takes a function $f$, and outputs a function $L(f)$. To define what $L(f)$ is, one must define what it does on each point of its domain. $L(f)(x)$ is integrating $f$ from $0$ to $x$. One mapping is from functions to functions, the other is a real valued function. It can be confusing at first, I hope this clarifies it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use only $F$ you may write 
$$F = \int_0^{\cdot} f(t)\,dt.$$
This notation means that when you give an argument to $F$ it appears at the top of the integral: e.g.
$$F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt, \quad F(x^2) = \int_0^{x^2}f(t)\,dt, \dots$$

Since $x$ is a variable, the integral $\int_0^x f(t)\,dt$ is a function of $x$.

Finally, since $L(f) = F$, you cannot simply write $L(f) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, because the right hand side is $F(x)$, not only $F$. Instead, you may write
$$L(f)(x) = F(x) = \int_0^x f(t)\,dt.$$